# Oracle performance and join with OR

Tags: oracle, performance, join

I sometimes have a problem with the connection and the "OR" clause. The example is simplified, but it shows the meaning of the question:

```
select a.ID, b.ID
from table a
  left join table2 b on (a.ID = b.ID)
```

Results: 20k Rows and 0.2s

```
select a.ID, b.ID
from table a
  left join table2 b on (a.ID2 = b.ID2)
```

Results: 20k Rows and 0.2s

```
select a.ID, b.ID
from table a
  left join table2 b on (a.ID = b.ID or a.ID2 = b.ID2)
```

Results: 20k Rows and time is 30s!

Platform: Oracle 11xe linux.

Why is there such a difference in execution time?

Comment: Your query is not valid SQL to start with. Where do you define `b`?

Comment: "b" is alias of table2

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--including cut & paste & runnable minimal code & minimal representative data given as code. For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL, including constraints, indexes & tabular initialization. For SQL performance that includes EXPLAIN results & statistics. Please research & summarize. For SQL that includes basics of optimization/performance--immediately leading to indexes, plans, statistics & SARGability. [Tips for asking a good SQL question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271056/3404097) Ask re optimization after you have learned & applied those basics. [ask]

Comment: Please clarify via edits, not comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

scaisEdge's answer provides a specific solution but it's also worth learning the generic reason why `OR` conditions in joins can cause performance issues - `OR` conditions prevent the optimizer from using hash joins.

Hash joins are usually the fastest way to join a large percentage of data. (Your tables may be small but since there are no filters they are processing a large percentage of data.) But hash joins can only work with equality conditions. To process an `OR` condition, Oracle will have to use a slower join method, like a sort merge or a nested loop.

If you think of the number of rows from the two tables as `M` and `N`, a hash join can (theoretically) be done in `M+N` operations, whereas a sort merge join can be done in `M*LOG(N)`. If you're curious, [this sample chapter](https://github.com/ProOracleSQL/presentations/blob/master/Chapter%2016%20-%20Pro%20Oracle%20SQL%20Development.pdf) contains more details about Oracle's different join types and how their performance compares.

A `UNION` version has to join the tables twice, but two fast joins can be better than one slow join. Oracle can't always convert an `OR` to `UNION` or `UNION ALL` because those two versions may not necessarily return the same rows as your other queries. For example, the `UNION` alternatives would treat duplicate rows differently. (But maybe you know something about your data that Oracle doesn't, so the queries may still work fine for you.)

This knowledge is useful because `OR` is not inherently slow and we don't always want to avoid it. If the `OR` is just part of an index access, or part of a join that won't use a hash join anyway, then there's nothing wrong with it.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of OR  try use UNION

```
select a.ID, b.ID
from tablea a
left join tableb b a.ID = b.ID
UNION 
select a.ID, b.ID
from tablea a
left tableb b join a.ID2 = b.ID2
```

or UNION ALL

```
select a.ID, b.ID
from tablea a
left join tableb b a.ID = b.ID
UNION  ALL
select a.ID, b.ID
from tablea a
left tableb b join a.ID2 = b.ID2
```

Comment: I can't use uni, because this is a query consisting of 30 connections between tables... ;) Only this one join causes such a delay. but I'm gonna try to break this one call (LEFT JOIN) into two..

Comment: Hmm, select a.ID, b.ID from table a left join table2 b on(b.id = a.id) left join table2 c on(c.id2 = a.id2) work fine!

Answer (score 0):

It's not really possible to answer a performance question like this without an execution plan. If I had to guess, I'd suspect you have an index on a.id and b.id, but not on a.id2 and b.id2.